# Removing sections from a string in Swift

Tags: swift

All,

If I have this string :

```
LE7 3JJ, 2, Bellyache Road, Sheepshead
```

How can I remove the characters and the first comma, so it comes out as :

```
2, Bellyache Road, Sheepshead
```

Do I do this with ranges in swift ? I want to write this as an Extension of string like :

```
extension String {

    func removeStringToFirstComma(input:String) -> String {


        return 
    }
}
```

Comment: is your string always going to be the same format or the same for that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
let str = "LE7 3JJ, 2, Bellyache Road, Sheepshead"
if let firstComma = str.rangeOfString(",") {
    let res = str.substringFromIndex(advance(firstComma.startIndex, 2))
    println(res)
}
```

First, you find the location of the first comma in the string. If it is there, **advance the index by two to skip over the comma and the adjacent space character**, and take the substring that starts at that index.

To adapt this snippet to your function, return the original string from the `else` branch of the conditional (not shown above).

Comment: Be sure to have a space after the comma in this case!